# Googlemaps in Python

Tags: python

How can i Integrate GoogleMaps in python ?! so that the maps can appear in python shell ?????

Comment: Maybe ASCII Google Maps?

Answer (score 3):

Python shell is not a graphical interface, it's a text interface. However you could display an html page in your favorite browser that you can create using python, where you embed google maps

---

you can use the [google maps api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/) to embed google maps in your own website and applications, and overlay your own data on top of them.

Answer (score 0):

No.

The Shell is not a graphical environment. You might be able to get them onto a window using any of the many windowing toolkits, but GoogleMaps are really intended for the browser...

Martin.